# Synchronization between different programs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have an automation system which consists of a series of programs each doing a specific task. Let's say I've one program called 'Downloader.py' which downloads some text file, 'Processor.py' which processes the file, and 'Uploader.py' which uploads the processed file. So, instead of carrying out serial execution, I've experimented and found out that if these tasks are carried out in parallel, the efficiency is much higher. So, now I run 2 instances of the downloader (which downloads multiple text files simultaneously), 5 instances of the processor (as processing is much slower, so any free file to be processed is processed quickly and simultaneously), and 1 instances of uploader (very fast, hence will upload the processed file as soon as it's ready).

So now to sync between the instances, I've used a local MySql database, which then stores a queue of the files to be processed. So, if one instance picks up one file (marked 'ready'), I mark it in the database as 'underprocessing', so the other instance processes the next 'ready' file.

Now, the problem is that sometimes 2 instances are picking up the exact same file and processing the same thing. So, is there any way to solve this problem without locking the database. (Tried this but it's too slow because in my application there're 12 different programs, each having 5~6 instances all pinging one database at the same time)

Any other approach not involving database is also accepted, need some sort of mutex in the end.
Note: The entire code is in Python 3.7

Comment: Check out the `queue` module. It's designed for precisely this sort of problem.

Comment: There's no single program that wraps all the instances. If the next day I need more downloaders, I just run another downloader.py. Not sure how the queue model would help in managing different programs altogether.

Comment: You said you would accept another approach not involving the database. That is going to require some recasting of code. Start by writing a controller program that just does the queueing. Have it import your other three programs, `downloader`, `uploader` and `process`, and use `threading` to call their main functions as many times as you want.

Comment: Yeah but maintaining instances will be much harder and not as free as I've currently. Plus I've to re write everything, which is a huge system. Basically I've a function which all programs call to get data from dB. So looking for answers where I can modify that function in any way possible rather than changing the whole code.

Comment: Are you still looking for solutions or figured out something?